# What is same as fflush function in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, fflush

Linux manual recommends that the `fflush` function should not be used.

So, I found that `while( getchar() != '\n'` plays the same role as `fflush(stdin)`.

e.g.)

my trial code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    char input[100] = {};
    printf("abcd");
    while(1);
}
```

If I execute the code above in Linux (Ubuntu), the result is nothing. Because `\n` is not in string. So, I have to print them out by emptying `stdout` buffer.

The strange phenomenon is that the result is printed well when I use either `getc(stdout)` or `getc(stdin)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    char input[100] = {};
    printf("abcd");
    getc(stdout); // or getc(stdin); both working well.
    while(1);
}
```

I don't know why both are done well. I expected that only `getc(stdout)` should work well because I regard `stdin` as keyboard buffer and `stdout` as monitor buffer.

Comment: Which manual did you saw, and what exactly is it saying? Very unclear question

Comment: My manual is written in my language, and it just say don't use fflush function.

Comment: If your manual says that `fflush` is useless, it is very wrong. Change to some better manual.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch fflush on stdin is indeed useless. No need to change manuals.

Comment: I am understanding the [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) as `fflush` on `stdin` when it is a tty is *undefined behavior*

Comment: Thank you for good comments. I've gotta read english manual.

Answer (score 2):

Read carefully the documentation of [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) (for input streams, it has a documented effect only on *seekable* files, not on *stdin* when it is a terminal). AFAIK, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior (when *stdin* is a terminal), and certainly does not do the same as 
`while( getchar() != '\n'`; you should call `fflush` on some *output* `FILE*` handle or on `NULL`

Your first example would work as expected if you add a `fflush(NULL);` or a `fflush(stdout);` call before the `while(1);` busy waiting loop (actually, you should call [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) inside that loop, at least to avoid heating your processor).

Notice that *stdin* can (on Linux) be a [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html), or a file or a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (e.g. with shell redirection or pipelines), etc....

Terminals, that is ttys, are -mostly for historical reasons- quite complex things. Read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page. In many situations, you have some *double* buffering: the kernel is buffering the tty thru its [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline), and the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) is buffering the *stdin*. See [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html). Of course a tty is not the keyboard (but some abstraction above it). Very likely, on your Linux desktop, the physical keyboard is *only* read by the [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server.

If you care about interactive input from a *terminal*, consider using some library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or [readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline)

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)

And the behavior of your second case can be explained by the fact that some C standard libraries are *implicitly* flushing *stdout* before reading from *stdin*, but AFAIK this is not guaranteed, and you certainly should call *explicitly* `fflush` (in particular, for readability reasons) when needed!

Read the documentation of [getc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getc.3.html), it can fail (and probably would fail with `stdout`).

Comment: Ah, really? I knew so far they are the same. Omg.

Answer (score -1):

You can use setbuf(stdout, NULL); function call to get same effect as fflush(stdin).

Comment: Why one is stdout and the other is stdin??

Comment: stdin and stdout both are file streams.
you can use any one of them.

Comment: I think the answer is wrong. `fflush(stdin)` is undefined, and practically does nothing.

Comment: Please check this link "http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html" .
I may be wrong. but i think it should be applicable for both type of streams

Comment: I just read it. `fflush` has a documented effect on input `FILE*` only when they are seekable files, not for ttys.